# Exact Target Email Template without pre-formatted code

Tags: html-email, exacttarget

Does anybody know if it's possible to create an exacttarget email template - ET Template NOT a regular htmlPaste email - without any pre-embeded code?

The problem I'm having is ET automatically puts in head and body tags and wraps everything in a 600px wide table.

The 600px wide container overrides my code to make the email responsive for iphones.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, you must be trying to test a responsive template and email.

Here are a couple of work-arounds:

1. ExactTarget Support can disable the default headers and footers with a special business rule.
2. Create a [Delivery Profile](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/admin/send_classifications/) that includes blank header and footers (either none or blank content areas) and send your tests using a a [Guided Send](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/guided_send/) with the Delivery Profile

Comment: Thanks for the reply Adam. I'll suss it out.

Answer (score 0):

i beleive you can create a support ticket to update the Default Header & Footer in the Exact target Application.

Responsive Header block should contain:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
```

Responsive Footer block should contain:

```
</html>
```

This will do the trick.
Hope it helps:)